# Does KMongo support enums?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, enums, kmongo

I have a mongo collection in which there is a String field called `role`. This field in particular will always be filled with one of these three options: `user`, `admin` or `guest`.

This is the reason why I decided to create an enum so it makes it easier for developers to work with it while keeping the String value in the database.

I have tried to retrieve a document from my collection expecting KMongo to be able to parse from String to Enum `Role` and vice versa.

Sadly, KMongo does not seem to be able to do it.

```
data class User(var role: Role,  // 0 user, 1 admin, 2 guest
                var email: String,
                var password: String)

enum class Role{
    user,
    admin,
    guest
}
```

When I tried to find a document by its `_id` I got this message:

> 2019-05-21 11:39:01 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR
>   c.p.p.c.SpringWebConfig$simpleMappingExceptionResolver$resolver$1 -
>   Excepción general resolviendo una petición
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException:
>   Instantiation of [simple type, class com.foo.user.User] value failed
>   for JSON property role due to missing (therefore NULL) value for
>   creator parameter role which is a non-nullable type  at [Source:
>   de.undercouch.bson4jackson.io.LittleEndianInputStream@3195529c; pos:
>   275] (through reference chain: com.foo.user.User["Role"])

So my question is: does KMongo support enums in these terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a solution for my issue. Using the [Jackson Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) library I can serialize and deserialize my enums the way I need. In my case, I chose to use them as Strings so KMongo knows how to work with them.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
enum class Role {
    user,
    admin,
    guest
}
```

Now I can just declare my attributes as my enum type so KMongo knows what to do with them.